# IntelliJ call hierarchy with dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, call-hierarchy

In IntelliJ, it is possible to decompile single class from a dependency jar and see that there is a function call to our prod class. But this is not useful for finding all calls to the method.

There is an option to include dependencies in call hierarchy feature (Ctrl+Alt+H), but seems like it doesn't work for a specific case.

To use this functionality of searching dependencies, should source code of dependency be available?
Does this mean that IntelliJ can index only dependencies with source code?

Thanks

Comment: Does "find usages" tool with predefined Scope work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that I met the same puzzle like you did, I click the notice upper under the tag "download the source" and it makes!
I can use "open call hierarchy" function to see the function hierarchy in source code.